# Push not received in gcm receiver

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I know this question has been asked a lot. I looked into many answers but my problem was not solved. I am sharing my code. Problem is that when I start my device, the receiver is executed (when I am using nexus 4 in my emulator). But when I connect my phone lenovo vibe k5 plus, it does not fire the receiver on starting the app.

Now when I send a push from parse, the push is not received neither in the phone nor in the emulator. I have little knowledge of sending pushes. I am struggling since a week..

My manifest:

```
 <receiver
        android:name="com.bison.d2d1.GcmBroadcastReceiver"
        android:exported="true"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
            <category android:name="com.bison.d2d1" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>


    <!-- Register Service -->

    <service android:name="com.bison.d2d1.GCMNotificationIntentService"
        android:enabled="true" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
    </intent-filter>
    </service>
```

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
```

Receiver:

```
public class GcmBroadcastReceiver extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        ComponentName comp = new ComponentName(context.getPackageName(),
                GCMNotificationIntentService.class.getName());
        startWakefulService(context, (intent.setComponent(comp)));
        setResultCode(Activity.RESULT_OK);





    }
```

Intent Service:

```
 public class GCMNotificationIntentService extends IntentService {
        // Sets an ID for the notification, so it can be updated
        public static final int notifyID = 9001;
        NotificationCompat.Builder builder;

        public GCMNotificationIntentService() {
            super("GcmIntentService");
        }

        @Override
        protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
            try {

    //            InstanceID instanceID = InstanceID.getInstance(this);
    //            String token = instanceID.getToken(getString(R.string.gcm_defaultSenderId),
    //                    GoogleCloudMessaging.INSTANCE_ID_SCOPE, null);

                Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
                GoogleCloudMessaging gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(this);


                String messageType = gcm.getMessageType(intent);

                if (!extras.isEmpty()) {
                    if (GoogleCloudMessaging.MESSAGE_TYPE_SEND_ERROR
                            .equals(messageType)) {
                        sendNotification("Send error: " + extras.toString());
                    } else if (GoogleCloudMessaging.MESSAGE_TYPE_DELETED
                            .equals(messageType)) {
                        sendNotification("Deleted messages on server: "
                                + extras.toString());
                    } else if (GoogleCloudMessaging.MESSAGE_TYPE_MESSAGE
                            .equals(messageType)) {
                        sendNotification("Message Received from Google GCM Server:nn"
                                +"");

                    }

                }
                else{
                    Toast.makeText(GCMNotificationIntentService.this, "messageType is empty", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                GcmBroadcastReceiver.completeWakefulIntent(intent);

            }catch (Exception e){
                Log.e("error",e.getMessage());
            }
        }

        private void sendNotification(String msg) {

            Intent resultIntent = new Intent(this, BoxedHome.class);
            resultIntent.putExtra("msg", msg);
            PendingIntent resultPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
                    resultIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

            NotificationCompat.Builder mNotifyBuilder;
            NotificationManager mNotificationManager;

            mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

            mNotifyBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                    .setContentTitle("D2D")
                    .setContentText(msg)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
            // Set pending intent
            mNotifyBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);

            // Set Vibrate, Sound and Light
            int defaults = 0;
            defaults = defaults | Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS;
            defaults = defaults | Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;
            defaults = defaults | Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;

            mNotifyBuilder.setDefaults(defaults);
            // Set the content for Notification
    //        mNotifyBuilder.setContentText("New message from Server");
            // Set autocancel
            mNotifyBuilder.setAutoCancel(true);
            // Post a notification
            mNotificationManager.notify(notifyID, mNotifyBuilder.build());
        }
    }
```

I will be grateful to any help. I have been struggling for a long time.

Comment: Are you using gcm or Parse?

Comment: My backend uses parse.

Comment: I'm recommending you to use the new version - Firebase. Its more easy and useful, and you have great guide in their docs.

Comment: Ok but can you guide me her too about what is the problem and how can i get it to work?

Comment: guess you would have googled inough. But still look into this sample http://www.androidhive.info/2016/02/android-push-notifications-using-gcm-php-mysql-realtime-chat-app-part-2/

Comment: ok thanks Stallion